# Re-enable Chrome browser remember password

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

For some websites, I have set the option `never on this site` when the browser recommends me to remember the password.

Now I want the popup comes back for this web, how can I do it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### 2023 Update

*Chrome's UI has once again significantly changed since the 2021 update. Now the Google Password Manager handles passwords.*

##### Quick Method

*Thanks @[Michael](https://superuser.com/users/576332/michael)*

1. In the address bar enter `chrome://password-manager/settings`
2. Scroll down a bit to the `Declined sites and apps` section
3. Delete the site(s) you want Chrome to prompt you again by clicking on the 'x' on the end of the row

##### Using the UI

1. Click the menu button near the top right of your Chrome
2. Click Settings
3. On the left hand side, click on `Autofill and passwords`
4. Click on `Google Password Manager`, this will open in a new tab or window depending on your settings
5. In the `Password manager` tab, on the left hand side, click on Settings
6. Scroll down a bit to the `Declined sites and apps` section
7. Delete the site(s) you want Chrome to prompt you again by clicking on the 'x' on the end of the row

### 2021 Update

*Chrome's UI has significantly changed since this was originally answered. As mentioned in the comments, back in 2017 the UI looked different but the steps to follow were pretty much the same. However, now Chrome's setting UI has changed so much so that a couple of the steps from the original answer are no longer applicable.*

1. Click the menu button near the top right of your Chrome
2. Click Settings
3. In the second section titled `Autofill`, click on `Password Manager`
4. Scroll down to the last section titled `Never Saved` (this section will appear after the `Saved Passwords` section)
5. Delete the site(s) you want Chrome to prompt you again by clicking on the 'x' on the end of the row

### Original Answer

1. Click the menu button near the top right of your Chrome.
2. Click Settings
3. At the bottom, click `Show advanced settings...`
4. Scroll down to the `Passwords and forms` section, your `Offer to save passwords I enter on the web.` option should be already checked (if not, check it)
5. Click `Manage saved passwords`.
6. In the second section, `Never saved`, delete the site(s) you want Chrome to prompt you again by clicking on the 'x' next to the site.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Chrome's interface has changed pretty significantly since this was answered, but it still functions the same way.

Comment: Odd. I do not see a certain site (for a bank if it matters) listed on "never saved" which doesn't let chrome to offer to remember, however, I do see it being offered on other browsers. What's the reason in that case?

Comment: I cannot say for sure, could you share a link to the login form? Some banks do not use standard input fields for passwords (I know of a bank that has a separate input field for each character), so it is very possible that this bank is doing something weird as well that prevents Chrome from recognizing the field as a password field for a login.

Comment: `chrome://password-manager/settings`